# The notion of (uniformly) bounded analytic semigroups

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, semigroups, semigroup-of-operators

From the book "$C_0$-semigroups and Applications" of Vrabie, we have this defintion of uniformly bounded analytic semigroups:

*Definition 7.1.1.* Let $\mathbb{C}_\theta=\{z \in \mathbb{C} ;-\theta<\arg z<\theta\}$.

We say that the $C_0$-semigroup $\{S(t) ; t \geq 0\}$ is analytic, if there exists $0<\theta \leq \pi$, and a mapping $\tilde{S}: \overline{\mathbb{C}}_\theta \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(X)$ such that:

(i) $S(t)=\tilde{S}(t)$ for each $t \geq 0$;
(ii) $\tilde{S}(z+w)=\tilde{S}(z) \tilde{S}(w)$ for each $z, w \in \overline{\mathbb{C}}_\theta$;

(iii) $\lim _{z \in \overline{\mathbb{C}}_\theta, z \rightarrow 0} \tilde{S}(z) x=x$ for each $x \in X$;
(iv) the mapping $z \mapsto \tilde{S}(z)$ is analytic from $\mathbb{C}_\theta$ to $\mathcal{L}(X)$.

If, in addition, for each $0<\delta<\theta$, the mapping $z \mapsto \tilde{S}(z)$ is bounded from $\mathbb{C}_\delta$ to $\mathcal{L}(X)$, the $C_0$-semigroup $\{S(t) ; t \geq 0\}$ is called **analytic and uniformly bounded.**

---

Thence, if I'm not mistaken, uniformly bounded means bounded on all the subsectors. However, in many papers, the authors talk about "bounded analytic semigroups" without the term "uniformly". Is it a matter of terminology?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the littrature, many authors use different termenology to mean the same thing: *bounded analytic*, *bounded holomorphic*, *uniformly bounded analytic*,  *uniformly bounded holomorphic*,..

Note that a semigroup might be (uniformly) bounded on the real axis but not on a sector.

To be sure, I recommend to refer to the definition given in the reference in consideration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.